# C++/winRT CreateFolderAsync - how to check for existing folder?

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm attempting to update a file in a folder. First I need to check if the folder exists and if not create one and then create an empty file in that folder.
A try/catch with CreationCollisionOption of FailIfExists or OpenIfExists
does not work if the folder does not exist.;

The other options:  GenerateUniqueName and ReplaceExisting are not appropiate.
code:............
//get the storage folder
    StorageFolder _storageFolder = ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder();

```
//get one of it's sub folders
StorageFolder _turboCalc = nullptr; //no default constructor
bool _folderFound = false;
try {
    _turboCalc = co_await _storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(L"TurboCalc", CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists); //create sub folder in sub folde
      //_turboCalc = co_await _storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(L"TurboCalc", CreationCollisionOption::FailIfExists); //create sub folder in sub folde
}
catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex) {
    _folderFound = false;
}
StorageFile  _fileDoubles = nullptr; //no default constructor
if (!_folderFound) { //creae the folder and an empty file
    _turboCalc = co_await _storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(L"TurboCalc");
    _fileDoubles = co_await _turboCalc.CreateFileAsync(L"FileDoubles.dbo", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting); //create file in sub folder
}
```

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that `OpenIfExists` does exactly what you want. Can you post the relevant part of your code here, please? You can't "check if the folder exists and if not create [it]" as two steps without race conditions, incidentally.

Comment: StorageFolder _storageFolder = ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder();
 
 //get one of it's sub folders
 StorageFolder _turboCalc = nullptr; //no default constructor
 bool _isFoulderFound = true;
 try {
  _turboCalc = co_await  _storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(L"TurboCalc", CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists);
 }
 catch (winrt::hresult_error const & e) {
  _isFoulderFound = false;
 }

 if (!_isFoulderFound){
  _turboCalc = co_await _storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(L"TurboCalc");
 }

Comment: Edit your question and include the code, rather than putting it in a comment, please.

Comment: **Edit your question**

Answer (score -1):

This is the behavior of a co-routine. Prob;em solved